# the hidden comic effect in one limerick

Tags: meaning, poetry, jokes

> There was a young rustic named Mallory,
>   who drew but a very small salary.
>   When he went to the show,
>   his purse made him go
>   to a seat in the uppermost gallery.

Can you explain to me the point of this limerick? Are the three last lines meant literally or figuratively? I am not able recognize the comic effect except some vague sort of paradox.

Comment: I think the problem here is that limericks are usually made for comic effect, but this one appears not to be. I certainly can't see any jokes or puns, which is confusing if you're expecting one.

Comment: This limerick actually appears to be one of the earliest published ones, dating from 1880 (http://www.thehypertexts.com/The%20Best%20Limericks%20of%20All%20Time.htm).

Comment: The only "humor" I see here is the dactylic rhyme "Mallory / salary / gallery", which sounds kind of funny.

Answer (score 17):

It's saying that the subject of the poem, Mallory, did not get paid much, so when going to the theater he had to settle for the worst, farthest away seats.

Comment: you nailed it. +1 for the quickness. I was writing this!

Comment: But the word "uppermost" has the positive connotation. So I thought that despite his poverty he could seat in the good position.

Comment: @bart-leby: This is the physically uppermost position - it's far away from the performance.

Comment: In an auditorium or pavilion the uppermost seats are bit 'cheaper'. The reason is the 'distance'. The first row down has better and closer view of the artists playing roles.

Comment: Yes, you are most likely right. I was confused by wrong understanding the word "uppermost". The last three verses of the limerick in fact confirm in one example the general characterization from the beginning. Thank you for your help.

Comment: These uppermost seats are in what is sometimes called the "nosebleed" section because of their "high altitude".

Comment: Also know as "the gods" due to their proximity to heaven. :-)